# XML Odata with Windows Phone 7 / 8 lib or best practice

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, odata

I would like to use this xml file : http://skalae.fr/cdt_Evenement.xml
but i do not know where to start...

How could i retreive all "flower market" or all "market" ?

How could i get some informations about one market ?

Is there any lib or sample using that kind of xml datas (french offices de tourisme) please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would either be to use an XML Serializer to deserialize the xml into objects, or to use LINQ to Xml to scan through the data and use what you wish.

Example of using XML Serializer with an Isolated Storage Xml File: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2010/08/31/windows-phone-7-xml-isolatedstorage-example.aspx

Examble of using LINQ to Xml generically: http://jesseliberty.com/2011/02/15/linq-to-xml/

Comment: So, i have to do that ?             var events1 = from e in datas.Descendants("object")
                          where
                              e.Element("cdt:InformationsGenerales").Element("cdt:EvenementType").Element(
                                  "cdt:Type_niv1").Element("cdt:Type").Attribute("jcr:uuid").Value ==
                              "3dc75250-d2da-4b19-9a4c-0a434143caaa"
                          select e;

Comment: There are a lot of .Element("xx") no ?

Comment: Xelement element = xDoc.Root.Element("cdt:InformationsGenerales").Element("cdt:EvenementType").Element( "cdt:Type_niv3").Element("cdt:Type") This should select the Flower Market Element container.